# why doesn't eval declare in a function work in bash?

Tags: bash, function, eval

Tracking down strange behavior a `bash` script resulted in the following MWE:

```
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -x
my_eval()
{
  eval "$1"
}
my_eval "declare -A ASSOC"
ASSOC[foo]=bar
echo success
```

fails with: `line 9: foo: unbound variable`. Yet it works if `eval` is used in place of `my_eval` (and, obviously, if the `declare` is done directly, without any indirection).

Why does `eval`ling a `declare` statement in a function not work the same as doing it outside of a function?

I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, from the popular `Ubuntu` distribution of `Linux`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A glance at the `man` pages tells us:

```
The -g option forces variables to be created or modified at the
global scope, even when **declare** is executed in a shell function.
```

Thus, if your script would say:

```
my_eval "declare -gA ASSOC"
```

it/you would be happier.

The point is that the "declare" statement sees its scope at where it is executed/evaluated, and not at where it is written.

Comment: Ah, well spotted. I thought `eval` was causing the trouble, but in fact it was being caused by `declare` being in a function.

Comment: The point is that `declare` makes variables **local** by default.